# How to detect non-transparent shape corner of a png image with Python?

Tags: python-2.7, png, pixel

I would like to determine the pixels of corner of  non-transparent shape of a png image with Python?
Here is the image [image]. For better understanding the transparent area marked red color as:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('image.png')
columnsize,rowsize=img.size
img = img.convert("RGBA")


for i in range(rowsize):
    for j in range(columnsize):
        X=img.getpixel((j,i))
        print X
```

Comment: You've shared a JPEG with a white background not a PNG with a transparent background? You haven't said what output you actually want - the trimmed image? the coordinates of the corners of the opaque part? Also, this seems to be the early stages of a project so why use Python 2 which is discontinued?